# How to split an input into multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In this input users will have to enter some coordinates.
I want to make an input that has multiple fields where users can enter only numbers and those fields will be separated by hard coded special  characters like ° " '

The result should give me a value like this 2°48'00.2"N 42°12'28.8"W

Something similar is when you introduce your card expiry date when shopping online and that / is already there and gets skipped when you introduce the month or the first 2 characters.

The approach I was thinking is to make a separate input/label for each field/character and then concatenate the values in javascript.

But making all those inputs and getting all those values in separate variables does not seem like a nice practice. And I would like to give the input placeholder something like [00°00'00.0"N 00°00'00.0"W] so the user will have an idea about the format.

Hopefully i have expressed myself clearly enough!!

Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use one of those input formatting libraries like [cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/). Here's my implementation using this library:

```js
var cleaveCustom = new Cleave('.input', {
  delimiters: ['°', '\'', '.', '"'],
    blocks: [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    uppercase: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cleave.js/1.5.10/cleave.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" placeholder="Enter your coordinates" length="10"/>
```

Comment: Quite close to what i was hoping to achieve.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds` function i'm returning your desired value. You can manipulate that.

```js
let latitude = 38.898556;
let longitude = -77.037852;
console.log(convertDMS(latitude, longitude));

function toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(coordinate) {
    var absolute = Math.abs(coordinate);
    var degrees = Math.floor(absolute);
    var minutesNotTruncated = (absolute - degrees) * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(minutesNotTruncated);
    var seconds = Math.floor((minutesNotTruncated - minutes) * 60);

    return degrees + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
}

function convertDMS(lat, lng) {
    var latitude = toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat);
    var latitudeCardinal = lat >= 0 ? "N" : "S";

    var longitude = toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng);
    var longitudeCardinal = lng >= 0 ? "E" : "W";

    return latitude + " " + latitudeCardinal + "\n" + longitude + " " + longitudeCardinal;
}
```